# Two Dimensional Array and User Input

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a GUI that will create a board with (n, n) dimensions.

I.e if the user inputs 9, it will create a board with 9 rows and 9 columns

I created a 2D array but I'm having difficulties in how to implement the user input.

I have:

```
    BoardButtons button[][];
```

How would I instantiate that in the constructor?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Ah,yes I should have put that, I'm using Java

Comment: `BoardButtons button[][] = new BoardButtons[x][y];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick with the constructor

```
private BoardButtons[][] buttons;

public Board(int size){
    buttons = new BoardButtons[size][size];
}
```

Comment: What if the parameters are two other Objects?

Comment: @CenaMaine How could they be? You said the user inputs the size of the board. Could you give an example?